# How do you allow a webapp to add users to the system?

Tags: web-applications

In my app, i have something called "groups" which any user can create. The user can then add members to this group. Now this member could be already registered in the system or is a totally new to the system. For "in the system" users, it is easy but for "not yet in the system" my dilemma was whether to pre-register the new user and send the user an email saying all the details of what happened.

Now, the admin could have misspelled the members email and it went to the wrong email address. So for the new user who just received email, they might think the system is sending spam by auto-registering them.

I was thinking should it be mandatory for the user to be pre-registered before the admin could add to the group?

One option is when the admin adds new users(not yet in the system) to the group, the user's email is added to the group but there is no email sent to the new user. The user when willingly registers using the same email, then the user is already part of the group.

Now there are multiple options how the webapp treats the new email addresses

1. If the email address does not exist, then create a new user, send an activation link with temporary password to the email address
2. The webapp ignores the email address and notifies the Team admin to have the user pre-register prior to getting added to the team.

1 is more convenient and a better user experience but it has potential for someone to abuse the system for spamming

2 Is safe as the team admin and the member have already communicated prior to joining into the webapp, they register and then the admin can add the user as its own team member.

How do webapp handle these kind of situation? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details its hard to answer, but if users can add them selves to a system what is the value of admins?

I would advise against that, it just violates most tenants of security. If the users can be preregistered than you have some information about them. I would let the admins add them to the system with the known email address. When the user goes to register them self, if the email is not found send a notice to an admin, who can decide whether to add the user or fix the typo. The typo should be the rare occurrence (not the norm), so users should be able to activate themselves immediately most of the time.